# Creating a php if satement with an echo within an echo

Tags: php, echo

Good morning all, I am trying to do the below so  that the area name is echoed in the li if the type is not 'main'. However it is just outputting what is in the string, is there a way to do this successfully and save me creating 800 footer pages?

```
        <?php if ($type=="main" ) {
                echo '
                <ul class="footer-nav">
                <h2>Links</h2>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.php">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="upvc.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
                <li><a href="emergency.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
              </ul>';}
              else
                echo '
                <ul class="footer-nav">
                <h2>Links</h2>
                <li><a href="locksmiths-<?php echo $areaname ?>.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-<?php echo $areaname ?>.php">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-upvc-repairs-<?php echo $area-name ?>.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-<?php echo $area-name ?>-24hour.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
              </ul>'
  ?>
```

Comment: Thank you all for such fast responses !

Comment: I think a h2 being a direct child of a ul is invalid html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The shortest code

You can `echo` common data only once, Like I did..

The variable `$area-name` is invalid... I converted it as $area_name.

```
<?php 
    echo '<ul class="footer-nav"><h2>Links</h2>'; //common data
if ($type=="main")
    echo '
        <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services.php">Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="upvc.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
        <li><a href="emergency.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>';
else echo '
        <li><a href="locksmiths-'.$areaname.'.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-'.$areaname.'.php">Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-upvc-repairs-'.$area_name.'.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-'.$area_name.'-24hour.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>';
echo '</ul>';//common data
?>
```

Comment: I can only vote one as correct answer, and although they are, this is the one I used

Answer (score 4):

you can write your php code in HTML without double quotes like this:

```
<?php if ($type == "main"): ?>
    <ul class="footer-nav">
         <h2>Links</h2>
         <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
         <li><a href="services.php">Our Services</a></li>
         <li><a href="upvc.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
         <li><a href="emergency.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
     </ul>
<?php else: ?>
    <ul class="footer-nav">
        <h2>Links</h2>
        <li><a href="locksmiths-<?= $areaname ?>.php">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-<?= $areaname ?>.php">Our Services</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-upvc-repairs-<?= $area-name ?>.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
        <li><a href="services-<?= $area-name ?>-24hour.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Much cleaner than other answers, but doubt it match OP's request.

Comment: @sakuto, I guess he couldn't evaluate echo's in else part. so this should help him, I guess. didn't test it!

Comment: its `type==main` not `type==mail`

Answer (score 2):

- `$area-name` **is not valid variable name**, probably typo.
- seeing your html I recommend you to go through [Alternative syntax for control structures](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php)

Here is other way for better readability, first `echo` is removed.

```
<?php if ($type=="main" ): ?>
              <ul class="footer-nav">
                <h2>Links</h2>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.php">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="upvc.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
                <li><a href="emergency.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
              </ul>
<?php else: ?>
              <ul class="footer-nav">
                <h2>Links</h2>
                <li><a href="locksmiths-<?php echo $areaname; ?>.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-<?php echo $areaname; ?>.php">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-upvc-repairs-<?php echo $areaname; ?>.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-<?php echo $areaname; ?>-24hour.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
              </ul>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 2):

A better way to do it would to use the ternary operator, this way you dont need to repeat your HTML your only change the links:

```
<ul class="footer-nav">
    <h2>Links</h2>
    <li><a href="<?= ($type == "main" ? 'index.php' :     'locksmiths-'.$areaname.'.php') ?>">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?= ($type == "main" ? 'services.php' :  'services-'.$areaname.'.php') ?>">Our Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?= ($type == "main" ? 'upvc.php' :      'services-upvc-repairs-'.$areaname.'.php') ?>">Upvc repairs</a></li>
    <li><a href="<?= ($type == "main" ? 'emergency.php' : 'services-'.$areaname.'-24hour.php') ?>">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
</ul>
```

Alternatively, you may want to abstract out the data from your HTML into an array, this will make adding further links or making the links more dynamic (in database) much easier.

```
<?php
$links = [
    [
        'name' => 'Home',
        'main' => 'index.php',
        'area' => 'locksmiths-'.$areaname.'.php'
    ], [
        'name' => 'Our Services',
        'main' => 'services.php',
        'area' => 'services-'.$areaname.'.php'
    ], [
        'name' => 'Upvc repairs',
        'main' => 'upvc.php',
        'area' => 'services-upvc-repairs-'.$areaname.'.php'
    ], [
        'name' => 'Emergency 24/7',
        'main' => 'emergency.php',
        'area' => 'services-'.$areaname.'-24hour.php'
    ],
];
?>
<ul class="footer-nav">
    <h2>Links</h2>
    <?php foreach ($links as $link): ?>
    <li><a href="<?= ($type == "main" ? $link['main'] : $link['area']) ?>"><?= $link['name'] ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</ul>
```

Comment: Easily the winner :)

Answer (score 1):

This should fix your problem. 
You forgot to make the else a proper statement

```
        <?php if ($type=="main" ) {
            echo '
            <ul class="footer-nav">
            <h2>Links</h2>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.php">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="upvc.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
            <li><a href="emergency.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
          </ul>';}
          else {
            echo '
            <ul class="footer-nav">
            <h2>Links</h2>
            <li><a href="locksmiths-'.$areaname.'.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services-'.$areaname.'.php">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="services-upvc-repairs-'.$areaname.'.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
            <li><a href="services-'.$areaname.'-24hour.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
          </ul>';}
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have some syntax errors, Use like this

```
<?php if ($type=="main" ) {
                echo '
                <ul class="footer-nav">
                <h2>Links</h2>
                <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services.php">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="upvc.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
                <li><a href="emergency.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
              </ul>';
            }else{
                echo '
                <ul class="footer-nav">
                <h2>Links</h2>
                <li><a href="locksmiths-'.$areaname.'.php">Home</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-'.$areaname.'.php">Our Services</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-upvc-repairs-'.$areaname.'.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
                <li><a href="services-'.$areaname.'-24hour.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
              </ul>';
            }
  ?>
```

Be Sure about the variable name like I replaced `$area-name` to `$areaname`

Answer (score 1):

no need to put echo inside echo.. please follow bellow changes..

```
<?php if ($type=="main" ) :
            echo '
            <ul class="footer-nav">
            <h2>Links</h2>
            <li><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services.php">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="upvc.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
            <li><a href="emergency.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
          </ul>';
          else:
            echo '
            <ul class="footer-nav">
            <h2>Links</h2>
            <li><a href="locksmiths-'.$areaname.'.php">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="services-.'$areaname.'.php">Our Services</a></li>
            <li><a href="services-upvc-repairs-.'$area-name.'.php">Upvc repairs</a></li>
            <li><a href="services-'.$area-name.'-24hour.php">Emergency 24/7</a></li>
          </ul>'
    endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$areaname = 'wales';
$pages = [
    'index.php' => 'Home',
    'services.php' => 'Our Services',
    'upvc.php' => 'Upvc repairs',
    'emergency.php' => 'Emergency 24/7'
];
$area_urls = [
    "locksmiths-$areaname.php",
    "services-$areaname.php",
    "services-upvc-repairs-$areaname.php",
    "services-$areaname-24hour.php"
];
if($type != 'main')
    $pages = array_combine($area_urls, $pages);
// Output menu
echo "<h2>Links</h2>\n<ul class='footer-nav'>\n";
    foreach($pages as $link => $page)
        printf("\t<li><a href='%s'>%s</a></li>\n", $link, $page);
echo "</ul>\n";
```